# Automatic num-to-char conversion in R using apply and data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, apply

I'd like to calculate the mean difference of two columns of my `data.frame`, grouping by a third.

- `apply` doesn't even let me compute any arithmetic operation without explicit conversion of **already-numeric columns**.
- `data.table` makes the operation and grouping but **returns a character vector**.
- `dplyr` syntax returns numeric values correctly.

Why does apply() convert numeric vectors to character? Why does `data.table` convert the results to char?

```
library(dplyr); library(data.table)
a <- letters[c(1,1:9)]
b <- (1:10)/10
c <- sin(1:10)
dat <- data.frame(a,b,c)
table(dat$a)
typeof(dat$b) #double
dat$bb <- apply(dat, 1,function(x) x["b"])
typeof(dat$bb) #character
dat$bb <- apply(dat, 1,function(x) x["b"]-x["c"])
# Error in x["b"] - x["c"] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
tidydat <- dat %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(diffr = mean(b-c))
typeof(tidydat$diffr) #double
dt <- data.table(dat)
dt[,bb:=mean(b-c), by=a]
typeof(dt$bb) #character

> dt$bb
 [1] "-0.725384205816789" "-0.725384205816789" "0.158879991940133"  "1.15680249530793"   "1.45892427466314"  
 [6] "0.879415498198926"  "0.0430134012812109" "-0.189358246623382" "0.487881514758243"  "1.54402111088937"  
> tidydat$diffr
[1] -0.7253842  0.1588800  1.1568025  1.4589243  0.8794155  0.0430134 -0.1893582  0.4878815  1.5440211
```

---

**EDIT** *this `data.table` part is untrue, I was just modifying by reference an already existing `char` column, from @Akrun*

Comment: Further note:The `apply` part is also incorrect. The `apply` function coerces the row of values to an atomic vector. (So those values were no longer numeric when they were given to the arithmetic inline functions. You should have worked with `dat[-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `apply`, convert the dataset from `data.frame` to `matrix`

```
> is.matrix(apply(dat, 1, I))
[1] TRUE
```

and matrix can have only a single `class` i.e. if there is a character element, it converts the whole data into character.  Instead use `lapply` (if it is columnwise) or may also subset the `numeric` columns before doing the `apply`

```
out <- apply(dat[-1], 1,function(x) x["b"]-x["c"])
```

-output

```
> out
 [1] -0.7414710 -0.7092974  0.1588800  1.1568025  1.4589243  0.8794155  0.0430134 -0.1893582  0.4878815  1.5440211
> str(out)
 num [1:10] -0.741 -0.709 0.159 1.157 1.459 ...
```

---

The reason for change in behavior is that `vector` element have only a single class and in data.frame/data.table/tibble etc, the columns are the `list` elements and not rows i.e. class is specific to a column and not a row

---

Regarding the `data.table` case

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- as.data.table(dat)
> dt$bb <- NULL # in case if the character column was already created
> dt[,bb:=mean(b-c), by=a]
> str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a : chr  "A" "A" "B" "C" ...
 $ b : num  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1
 $ c : num  0.841 0.909 0.141 -0.757 -0.959 ...
 $ bb: num  -0.725 -0.725 0.159 1.157 0.704 ...
```

Comment: okay, thanks. why this behaviour with `data.table`? I understand your point about column-specific types, but the final result is `char `, not numeric. does that have sth to do with rounding and many digits?

Comment: @CatalystRPA If you are talking about the last piece of code, I can't reproduce it

Comment: okay please try `library(data.table)`, will precise the question

Comment: @CatalystRPA I am guessing that you created the 'dat' with `bb` already there while converting to `data.table`.  Instead do `dat$bb <- NULL` and start this fresh.

Comment: yes, you're right. so `data.table` will keep the original type of columns in some cases. thx

Comment: @CatalystRPA That is the reason you may have to be careful when using `:=` as this is assignment by reference

Answer (score 0):

I think [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68765162/12158757) has provided sufficient information for understanding the reason behind. Actually you can try the code below to see what's going on when you use `apply` by rows

```
> apply(dat, 1, str)
 Named chr [1:3] "a" "0.1" " 0.8414710"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "a" "0.2" " 0.9092974"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "b" "0.3" " 0.1411200"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "c" "0.4" "-0.7568025"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "d" "0.5" "-0.9589243"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "e" "0.6" "-0.2794155"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "f" "0.7" " 0.6569866"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "g" "0.8" " 0.9893582"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "h" "0.9" " 0.4121185"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 Named chr [1:3] "i" "1.0" "-0.5440211"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
NULL
```

As you can see, when you run `apply(dat,1,FUN = ...)` ,the data passed to `FUN` is coalesced to a vector of characters, instead of data.frame any more.